# Perl grep over array indexes

Tags: perl, grep

I've been trying to work out the following code, which ultimately returns the array  indexes of numbers in a list that have odd digit sums.

```
my @input_numbers = (1,2,4,8,16,32,64);
my @indices_of_odd_digit_sums = grep {
my $number = $input_numbers[$_];
my $sum;
$sum += $_ for split //, $number;
$sum % 2;
} 0..$#input_numbers;

print "@indices_of_odd_digit_sums";
```

I think have worked out that the script is using `$input_numbers[$_]`, as the grep is putting the array indices (0..6) into `$_`

This way $number is assigned the actual value of the list item.

I'm a bit unsure about what `$_` is in the line:

```
$sum += $_ for split //, $number;
```

Is $_ now each digit in the actual number? So for 16, it is first 1 and then 6. I'm not familiar with the 'for split' syntax.

Thanks for any help offered

John

Comment: And https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=322751, though with a lot of digression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_` is the [default variable](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$_). It is a global variable which happens to get set by default in various operations, like a for/foreach loop, and used by default by various functions. This allows you to write things like `print foreach @array;`.

The `for` is a [statement modifier](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) which is just another way to wrap the preceding statement in a [foreach loop](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops).

[split](https://perldoc.pl/functions/split) is a function which splits its argument using the given pattern, and returns a list of strings, which that foreach loop then iterates over, and aliases each element locally to `$_`.

So that statement could be expanded to:

```
foreach my $digit (split //, $number) {
  $sum += $digit;
}
```

It could also be simplified using [sum from List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#sum):

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my $sum = sum split //, $number;
```